# Replace URL during build step of npm

Tags: javascript, rest, npm, mocking, release

I've a mock REST service during development and a real backend I want to use for the public release. Is there a way to replace the endpoint URL somehow during the npm build step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` to measure whether it is at development environment or production environment.

It would be something like this:

```js
const baseUrl = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'localhost:3000' : 'www.live.com'
```

`localhost:3000` would be the backend url while you developing.